# Powershell - Cannont Find Appropriate constructor for System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy

Tags: sql, powershell, constructor, sqlbulkcopy

I'm looking to test importing data into SQL from an Excel file referencing a blog I came across online, but I'm not having much success.

Below is the code; I'm not sure what exactly I am doing wrong.

```
   function Import-Excel ($FolderPath, $XlsxFile, $Server, $Database, $Table) {
    # Create an Excel workbook...
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application;
    $Workbook = $Excel.WorkBooks.Open((Join-Path -Path (Convert-Path -Path $FolderPath) -ChildPath $XlsxFile));
    $WorkSheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets.Item(1);
    $StartRow = 2; # ...ignore headers...

    # Insert into a System.Data.DataTable...
    $DataTable = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataTable;
    $null = $DataTable.Columns.Add('PartNum', 'System.String');
    $null = $DataTable.Columns.Add('TagNum', 'System.String');

    # Load the DataTable...
    do {
        $PartNum = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($StartRow, 1).Value();
        $TagNum = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($StartRow, 2).Value();


        $Row = $DataTable.NewRow();
        $Row.PartNum = $PartNum;
        $Row.TagNum = $TagNum;
    
        $DataTable.Rows.Add($Row);
        $StartRow++;
        
            
    } while ($WorkSheet.Cells.Item($StartRow, 1).Value() -ne $null); #...until a gap in values...
    $Excel.Quit(); # ...then exit...
    # Bulk load it...
    $BulkCopy = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy -ArgumentList $ServerConnection;
    $SqlConnection.Open();
    $BulkCopy.DestinationTableName = $Table;
    $BulkCopy.WriteToServer($DataTable);
};

Import-Excel -FolderPath "C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop\" -XlsxFile "TestUpload.xlsx" -Server "TestSVR" -Database "TestDB" $ServerConnection = "Data Source=$Server;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=$Database" -Table "dbo.Tag_Test";
```

I can resort to using SSIS if needed, but was looking to work with PowerShell some.

Answer (score 4):

A neat PowerShell discovery feature is to list the overload definitions ( arguments for method and/or constructors).  I haven't worked with the Bulk copy class and you didn't mention the actual error, but run the following:

```
[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy]::new
```

> Note: the missing parenthesis.

This should give output like:

```
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy new(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy new(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions copyOptions, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction externalTransaction)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy new(string connectionString)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy new(string connectionString, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions copyOptions)
```

Also the BulkCOpy class is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1). MS usually doesn't give examples in PowerShell, but the C# is easy enough to understand, and often helps me figure questions such as these.

I'm sure that's not everything you need but let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Initialization of `$ServerConnection` variable is missing, it seems to be null.

Anyway, you could create bulko object in a different way:

`$BulkCopy = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy]::new(<arguments>)`.

You can use SqlConnection object or connectionString as an argument. If you need to see other constructors, then if you press ctrl+space after :: and pick new() with cursors,  PowerShell 7 console, Powershell ISE and VSCode will all list every available constructor in a hint.

Comment: Nice spot.  Note: PSReadLine module will provide Ctrl + Space functionality in earlier versions of PowerShell.  I believe that's what's really doing it in 7.x as well.  I have a love/hate relationship with it, but it certainly works in "Windows PowerShell" 5.1, where this particular feature is super handy.

Comment: @Steven I thought it was a PS 7 improvement, now I see I'm just using older PSReadline module in PS 5.